# Laravel Scout: search in multiple columns at once

Tags: laravel, laravel-9, laravel-scout

I have a database with people. Their names are divided into `first_name` and `last_name` columns. I use Laravel Scout with database engine to search for their full names.

Let's say I have *John Doe* in the database. Right now, if I search for *John*, I get the result (Scout finds it in the `first_name` column). If I search for *Doe*, I also get the correct result (it is found in the `last_name` column). However, searching for *John Doe* gives no result, as it is divided into two columns.

I have found a possible solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73167295/20556216), but it doesn't work for me. I have made a trait, which combines the two name parts into one, and it works in blade components (I can say `{{$person->fullName}}`), but it doesn't work for Laravel Scout. This is my `Person.php` file:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Laravel\Scout\Searchable;
use App\Helpers\PersonAttributes;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;

class Person extends Model
{
    use HasFactory, Searchable, PersonAttributes;

    public function toSearchableArray(): array
        {
            return [
                'fullName' => $this->fullName
            ];
        }
}
```

and this is my `PersonAttributes.php` file:

```
<?php

namespace App\Helpers;

trait PersonAttributes
{
    public function getFullNameAttribute(): string
    {
        return $this->first_name . " " . $this->last_name;
    }
}
```

The problem is, that when performing the search (`$person = Person::search(request("query"))->get();`), I get this error: `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'persons.fullName' in 'where clause'`, as it is trying to perform this SQL:

```
select * from `persons` where (`persons`.`fullName` like %whateverisearchfor%) order by `id` desc
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the easiest way to do it is not to use Laravel Scout at all and use just Eloquent instead. In the end, this is what I did:

```
$request = "%" . str_replace(" ", "%", request("query")) . "%";
$person_query = Person::query();
$person_query->where(DB::raw('concat(first_name, " ", last_name)'), 'like', $request);
$person = $person_query->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems your query is trying to select values from DB, not from Elastic. First of all, check [indexation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/scout#adding-records-via-query). Try to use something like this:

```
$search = 'Jonh Doe'
$query[] = [
    'match_phrase_prefix' => [
        'fullName' => [
            'query' => $search,
          ],
    ],
];

$query = [
    'bool' => [
        'must' => $query,
    ],
];

$result = Person::searchQuery($query)->get();
```

[Base information about Elastic](https://madewithlove.com/blog/software-engineering/basic-understanding-of-text-search/)

Hope it would lead you to the proper solution to your problem :)

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer, however, as I mentioned, I am using the new database engine, not Elasticsearch. That's why it's trying to get values from the database. When trying your code, I get an error `Call to undefined method App\Models\Person::searchQuery()`. It also doesn't work with `search()` method.

Comment: Sorry, my fault, I thought you have implemented the Elastic engine. Hmm, have you set SCOUT_DRIVER environment variable?

Comment: Yes, I have. And when I search based only on `first_name` (or only `last_name`), it works...